# how to access java webservices after hosting on server...accessing from localhost is working fine

Tags: java, android, web-services

i'm suffering problem how to access java-xs(java webservices) from android application.webservices and db file upload on server
i build android application in which server side make java webservices
but problem  its show error after access from server....anyone please know about please help me....
client side code 
this code is define server call to server. first send request to server and after server send response by using http protocal
all working fine but show error after uploadig on server
public class Servercalls
{
    public String response_str = "";

```
public void setResponse_str(String response_str) 
{
    this.response_str = response_str;
}

public HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
public HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://emailking.co.in/sarang_app/Real_state/rest1/server");
//public HttpPost httppost1 = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106:8090/Real_state/rest1/server");

public void servercall(String jsonstring)
{

    try
    {
        Log.d("Request to server",jsonstring);
        JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
        postjson.put(jsonstring);
        System.out.println(postjson.toString());
        System.out.println("Sumit kumawat......hi heellllo");
        httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonstring);
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response;
        System.out.println(httppost.toString());
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        if(response != null)
        {
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response_str = line;
                Log.d("Response from server", response_str.toString());
        }
        }
        // Toast.makeText(this, "success " + response_str,
        // 2000).show();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        Log.e("cpexception", "Error in client protocol" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("ioexception", "Error in io protocol" + e.toString());
        //response_str = "{error:\"1\"}";
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

}

logcat file

```
> 06-20 17:10:06.006 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> D/Request to server: {"wsfunction":"Getting_Project"} 06-20
> 17:10:06.006 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate I/System.out:
> ["{\"wsfunction\":\"Getting_Project\"}"] 06-20 17:10:06.006
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate I/System.out: Sumit
> kumawat......hi heellllo 06-20 17:10:06.012
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate I/System.out:
> org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@1faa484a 06-20 17:10:06.889
> 23264-23272/com.example.admin.realstate W/art: Suspending all threads
> took: 41.019ms 06-20 17:10:07.857
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate I/System.out:
> org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@10c383bb 06-20 17:10:07.858
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server:
> <!DOCTYPE html> 06-20 17:10:07.858
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server: <html
> style="height:100%"> 06-20 17:10:07.858
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server:
> <head><title> 404 Not Found 06-20 17:10:07.858
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server:
> </title></head> 06-20 17:10:07.859
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server: <body
> style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica,
> sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;"> 06-20 17:10:07.905
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server: <div
> style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align:
> center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%;
> left:50%;"> 06-20 17:10:07.905 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> D/Response from server:         <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px;
> line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">404</h1> 06-20 17:10:07.905
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server: <h2
> style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Not Found 06-20 17:10:07.906
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server: </h2>
> 06-20 17:10:07.909 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> D/Response from server: <p>The resource requested could not be found
> on this server!</p> 06-20 17:10:07.914
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server:
> </div></div><div style="color:#f0f0f0;
> font-size:12px;margin:auto;padding:0px 30px 0px
> 30px;position:relative;clear:both;height:100px;margin-top:-101px;background-color:#474747;border-top:
> 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255,
> 0.3) inset;"> 06-20 17:10:07.916 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate D/Response from server:
> <br>Proudly powered by  <a style="color:#fff;"
> href="http://www.litespeedtech.com/error-page">LiteSpeed Web
> Server</a><p>Please be advised that LiteSpeed Technologies Inc. is not
> a web hosting company and, as such, has no control over content found
> on this site.</p></div></body></html> 06-20 17:10:07.918
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate E/Exception In sarangbuilder/:
> org.json.JSONException: Value <br>Proudly of type java.lang.String
> cannot be converted to JSONObject 06-20 17:10:07.918
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate W/System.err:
> org.json.JSONException: Value <br>Proudly of type java.lang.String
> cannot be converted to JSONObject 06-20 17:10:07.923
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate W/System.err:     at
> org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) 06-20 17:10:07.924
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate W/System.err:     at
> org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160) 06-20 17:10:07.925
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate W/System.err:     at
> org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173) 06-20 17:10:07.925
> 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate W/System.err:     at
> com.example.admin.realstate.Constant.CheckSuccessResponse(Constant.java:20)
> 06-20 17:10:07.925 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> W/System.err:     at
> com.example.admin.realstate.Projects_Fragments$NewProject_cls.doInBackground(Projects_Fragments.java:196)
> 06-20 17:10:07.925 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> W/System.err:     at
> com.example.admin.realstate.Projects_Fragments$NewProject_cls.doInBackground(Projects_Fragments.java:171)
> 06-20 17:10:07.925 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
> 06-20 17:10:07.925 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> W/System.err:     at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 06-20
> 17:10:07.925 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate W/System.err:    
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 06-20
> 17:10:07.925 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate W/System.err:    
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
> 06-20 17:10:07.925 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> W/System.err:     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
> 06-20 17:10:07.925 23264-23785/com.example.admin.realstate
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 06-20
> 17:10:07.929 23264-23264/com.example.admin.realstate I/System.out:
> call postexecute 06-20 17:10:07.929
> 23264-23264/com.example.admin.realstate I/System.out: project list[]
> 06-20 17:10:07.933 23264-23264/com.example.admin.realstate
> I/System.out: Adapter constructor getting list[]
```

Comment: Your URL is not working. I just tried in browser. Can you confirm it

Comment: yeah its confirm in localhost working fine but after uploading on server show error....please see this link also http://emailking.co.in/sarang_app/

Comment: any configuration after uploading on server

Comment: Are you using apache-tomcat server in the localhost to deploy WAR file?

Comment: yes sir..i use war file on localhost

Comment: And, are you correctly deploying the WAR file in the server and running the tomcat?

Comment: but sir my company use another server....like cpanel for php they dont know about warfile...i just create webservices in java and access

Comment: please help sir why i cant access

Comment: So, you've to find out how to set up/run tomcat in your server and then proceed as you did in localhost.

Comment: on localhost all are working fine

Comment: Yes i got that. You've to first setup tomcat in your server like as you did in localhost.

Comment: any idea about... but tomcat inside server(means...)

Comment: Like installing tomcat in your GoDaddy server.

Comment: ohk sir...thank you but any example,link that is use to i get

Comment: [https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Introduction+to+Tomcat#IntroductiontoTomcat-HowtoinstallTomcat]